# Convert string to array of strings by regex

Tags: c#

What is the best way to achieve the following result?

input string: `this is a {test} for {performance}.`

output string[]: `["this is a ", "{test}", " for ", "{performance}", "."]`

This is what I have so far:

```
private void StringToArray(string text)
    {
        var firstSplit = text.Split('{');
        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach(var s in firstSplit)
        {
            if (s.Contains("}"))
            {
                var secondSplit = s.Split('}');
                list.Add("{" + secondSplit[0] + "}");
                if(secondSplit.Count() > 1)
                {
                    list.Add(secondSplit[1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(s);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list.ToArray()));
    }
```

Comment: I take it you are splitting on curly braces?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.  Show us your attempt and we'll help you get the rest of the way.

Comment: @Amy I am looking for good approach... not asking for code.

Comment: Take a look at split: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx you can split first by "{" and then by "}"

Comment: @JohnTortugo thanks thats what I have so far but not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Usually, there is always a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all computer-science-y, you could build a state machine that walks the string one character at a time, using a stack to track the start position for your next string section. When you find a `{` or `}` character, you pop the prior stack value and use it to create a substring you can add to your array. Then you push the current index onto the stack.

This can be more or less complex based on how carefully you want to handle nesting (ie: "`This is { a {test}.}`"), escape characters (ie: `{{` or `\{`), unbalanced strings (ie: `This {is} a {Test`), whitespace within brace values (ie: `This {is some} text`) or excluding things like quoted strings (ie: "`This is the text, "A {person} lived there."`") But a character-by-character state machine will tend to be the best-performing option.

At a higher level, you can look at a domain specific language, or using a lexxer/parser tool. Unfortunately, there's very little in the middle. RegEx can be made to work, but it's generally awful for this because your input can't be said to be formally "regular". Splitting on word boundaries will be error-prone. Basic string manipulation (ie: `IndexOf()`) is slower and no simpler or easier to write than the state machine would be.